# underscore.each will complete cycle instead await inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I've a _each() that inside got  an await where I check a user state in MySQL

the mysql response return after cycle is already completed.
there is a way that wait the method checkUserState(), beforse and than go to next element of _each()?

```
 let obj = _.each(guest_list.guests, async function (value){
     let user_state = await DataController.checkUserState('2305');
    value.Owner.state = user_state;
    console.log('state:' + user_state);
    return value;
  });

  console.log('cycle complete')
 return obj;
```

> Result is: cycle complete state:notdisturb state:notdisturb
> state:notdisturb state:notdisturb state:notdisturb state:notdisturb
> state:notdisturb state:notdisturb state:notdisturb state:notdisturb
> state:notdisturb state:notdisturb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **Promise.all**

```js
let obj = await Promise.all(_.map(guest_list.guests, async function (value){
     let user_state = await DataController.checkUserState('2305');
    value.Owner.state = user_state;
    console.log('state:' + user_state);
    return value;
  }));

  console.log('cycle complete')
 return obj;
```

Comment: _.each does not return an array, this is not going to work

Comment: is the same of my code, cycle finish before await

Comment: @RogerAI you need to _.map function instead of each or you need to use for loop.

Comment: Updated my answer as well please check now.